# irreducible representation extending as projection onto matrix algebra

Tags: representation-theory

I want to ask a question about some statement in Peter Webb's "A course in finite group representation theory", p40 (book on his website, not the published version)

Let $\rho_1,\ldots,\rho_r$ be irreducible representations of finite group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with degree $d_1,\ldots,d_r$ and character $\chi_1,\ldots,\chi_r$. It says that after extending by linearity $\rho_i:G\rightarrow M_{d_i}(\mathbb{C})$ to $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism $\rho_i: \mathbb{C}[G]\rightarrow M_{d_i}(\mathbb{C})$, we idetify $\mathbb{C}[G]$ with $\Pi_{j=1}^rM_{d_j}(\mathbb{C})$ by Artin-Wedderburn, then each $\rho_i:\Pi_{j=1}^rM_{d_j}(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_{d_i}(\mathbb{C})$ is a projection onto the $i$th matrix summand.

My question is why he can conclude that $\rho_i$ is a projection onto $M_{d_i}(\mathbb{C})$ or why $\rho_i$ is surjective. The book says it is because of the way we decompose $\mathbb{C}[G]$ as a sum of matrix algebra. But I have spent whole day on this problem and still can't figure it out.

Comment: Doesn't $\rho_i:\Pi_{j=1}^r M_{d_j}(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_{d_i}(\mathbb{C})$ satisfy the definition of a projection?

Comment: I don't know. Can we say that $\rho_i$ restricted on $M_{d_i}(\mathbb{C})$ is the identity map on it?

Answer (score 2):

This argument is from Proposition 7.2, p.382, and Lemma 8.3, p387, in Grillet's Abstract Algebra 2/e.

- Recall that
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  \Bbb{C}G
  &\cong& M_{d_1}(\Bbb{C})\oplus M_{d_2}(\Bbb{C})\oplus \cdots\oplus M_{d_r}(\Bbb{C})\\
  &\cong&
  \overbrace{S_1\oplus S_1\oplus \cdots\oplus S_1}^{d_1\text{-times}}\oplus \\
  && \overbrace{S_2\oplus S_2\oplus \cdots\oplus S_2}^{d_2\text{-times}}\oplus \\
  &&\cdots\oplus\\
  && \overbrace{S_r\oplus S_r\oplus \cdots\oplus S_r}^{d_r\text{-times}} \\
  &\cong&
  S_1^{d_1}\oplus S_2^{d_2}\oplus \cdots \oplus S_r^{d_r}.
  \end{eqnarray*}
  In fact,
  $$S_i\cong \left\{\left(0, ..., 0, \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \cdots & 0 & a_{1k} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & \cdots & 0 & a_{2k} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
  0 & \cdots & 0 &  a_{d_i k} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}, 0, ..., 0\right)\mid a_{1k}, a_{2k}, ..., a_{d_i k}\in \Bbb{C}\right\}$$
  for some $k\in \{1, 2, ..., d_i\}$.
- Since $\rho_i$ is an irreducible representation of $G$ over $\Bbb{C}$,
  let $L_i$ be the corresponding simple $\Bbb{C}G$-module.
  That is, $\rho_i:G\to GL(L_i)$.
- $L_i$ is isomorphic to a simple $\Bbb{C}G$-submodule $S_i$ of $\Bbb{C}G$.
  (See Theorem C-2.33 in Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra 3/e Part II.)
  So $\rho_i:G\to GL(S_i)$.
  In rigorous,
  we should write $L_i\cong 0\oplus \cdots \oplus 0\oplus S_i\oplus 0\oplus\cdots \oplus 0$.
- By the correspondence between the representations and modules,
  for any $\sum_{g\in G}z_g g\in \Bbb{C}G$ and $s\in S_i$,
  \begin{equation}
  \tag{1}
  \left(\sum_{g\in G}z_g g\right)\cdot s
  =\sum_{g\in G}z_g (\rho_i(g)(s)).
  \end{equation}
- We define $\overline{\rho_i}:\Bbb{C}G\to \text{End}_{\Bbb{C}}{(S_i)}$
  by $$\overline{\rho_i}\left(\sum_{g\in G}z_g g\right)
  =\sum_{g\in G}z_g \rho_i(g).$$
- For any
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  s
  &\in& S_i\\
  &\cong& 0\oplus \cdots \oplus 0\oplus S_i\oplus 0\oplus\cdots \oplus 0\\
  &\subseteq & 0\oplus \cdots \oplus 0\oplus M_{d_i}(\Bbb{C})\oplus 0\oplus\cdots \oplus 0\\
  &\subseteq & \Bbb{C}G
  \end{eqnarray*}
  and
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  x=\sum_{g\in G}z_g g
  &\in& M_{d_j}(\Bbb{C}) \text{ (Notice the subscript!)}\\
  &\cong& 0\oplus \cdots \oplus 0\oplus M_{d_j}(\Bbb{C})\oplus 0\oplus \cdots \oplus 0\\
  &\subseteq & \Bbb{C}G,
  \end{eqnarray*}
  where $j\neq i$,
  we have
  $x\cdot s=0$ because they are in the different components $M_{d_i}(\Bbb{C})$ and $M_{d_j}(\Bbb{C})$.
  In this case, we view $x\cdot s$ as a prodcut of two elements $x$ and $s$ in $\Bbb{C}G$.
  Then
  \begin{multline*}
  \overline{\rho_i}\left(x\right)(s)=
  \overline{\rho_i}\left(\sum_{g\in G}z_g g\right)(s)
  =\left(\sum_{g\in G}z_g \rho_i(g)\right)(s)\\
  =\sum_{g\in G}z_g (\rho_i(g)(s))
  \stackrel{(1)}{=}\left(\sum_{g\in G}z_g g\right)\cdot s
  =x\cdot s
  =0
  \end{multline*}
  It follows that $\overline{\rho_i}\left(x\right)=0$ if $x\in M_{d_j}(\Bbb{C})$ for $j\neq i$.
- For any $s\in S_i$
  and $x=\sum_{g\in G}z_g g\in M_{d_i}(\Bbb{C})$ (Notice the subscript!),
  \begin{multline*}
  \overline{\rho_i}\left(x\right)(s)
  =\overline{\rho_i}\left(\sum_{g\in G}z_g g\right)(s)
  =\left(\sum_{g\in G}z_g \rho_i(g)\right)(s)\\
  =\sum_{g\in G}z_g (\rho_i(g)(s))
  \stackrel{(1)}{=}\left(\sum_{g\in G}z_g g\right)\cdot s
  =x\cdot s.
  \end{multline*}
  In this case, we view the action of $x$ on $s$ as a linear transformation on $S_i$.
  It follows that $\overline{\rho_i}\left(x\right)=x$.
- In addition, $\text{End}_{\Bbb{C}}{(S_i)}\cong \text{End}_{\Bbb{C}}{(L_i)}\cong M_{d_i}(\Bbb{C})$.
  That is why the author says that $\overline{\rho_i}:\Bbb{C}G\to M_{d_i}(\Bbb{C})$ is a projection.